# Call a function after leaving input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

On a contact form, I have several input fields. One of those fields, is an email address field:

```js
<input type='text' name='input_email' onChange={this.validateEmail}/>
```

Right now, I have the email validation function set to the onChange attribute. Thus, while the user is entering characters into the email field, an error message appears the whole time.

I want to change this, so that `this.validateEmail` only gets called once when the user leaves that specific input field. How would I accomplish this?

I can't find any default object events that would solve this issue.

FYI, using ReactJS

Comment: Use `onblur`...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `onblur()` or `onfocusout()`. It will call function once you click out of that text field.

Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sometext");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sometext" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 13):

Note: As from React 16, onFocusIn and onFocusOut have been replaced by onFocus and onBlur respectively. Hence you now have:

```
<input type='text' name='input_email' onBlur={this.validateEmail}/>
```

Comment: This question is not about React. Your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The question does say "FYI, using ReactJS" so it seems reasonable.

Comment: @tdy didn't notice.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("blur", function() {
  alert("Hello World")
});
```

- [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)