# How to detect the deselection of a before selected text?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, textselection, custom-events

This may be a dumb question but I didn't find any information about this anywhere...

```html
<input type="text" onselect="javascript: sel1 = true" placeholder="Suche nach etwas" id="browser1">
```

I have this line and at `onselect` the var sel1 is on true. Now this is the problem: I don't know how to do the opposite. I want to know how I can set the var `sel1` to false when I deselect the input.

Comment: Have you tried onblur="sel1=false" ? I hope this could help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function after leaving input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791919/call-a-function-after-leaving-input-field)

Comment: just for noticing ... a `blur` event type is not the opposite of a `select` event type. Since the latter is dispatched for `text` type input fields and textareas whenever a text gets selected, the opposite was the deselection of such a text and not the defocusing of the element itself (it is possible to have selected text while having lost the element focus).

Comment: @Jan ... thus said. What is/was the purpose anyhow of handling the `select` event in first place?

Comment: @Jan ... Regarding the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @Jan ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback (don't just disappear) and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is as follows ...

- Utilize a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instance as text-element based ***storage*** for a text-element's most recent ***text selection state***.
- Enable a text-elements ***deselect detection*** ...

  - ... by keeping track of such an element's ***`'select'` event*** and ***selection state*** ...
  - ... and by following other events as well like e.g. `'keyup'`, `'mouseup'` and `'focusout'` where one always has to ***check the current selection state against the most recent one***.
- In case of having verified a deselection ***a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) is created and dispatched***. Thus one now can ***directly listen to and handle text element related `'deselect'` events***.

```js
// gather all text control related selection data and put it
// into an object based (here the element reference) storage.
function putTextSelectionState(textControl) {
  const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textControl;

  const isSelected = (selectionEnd - selectionStart >= 1);
  const selection = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

  textSelectionStorage.set(textControl, {
    isSelected,
    selection,
    selectionStart,
    selectionEnd,
    value,
  });
}
// the object based storage.
const textSelectionStorage = new WeakMap;

// detect whether custom 'deselect' event handling has to take place.
function handleDeselectText(evt) {
  const textControl = evt.currentTarget;
  const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textControl;

  // console.log({ type: evt.type, selectionStart, selectionEnd });

  const recentState = { ...textSelectionStorage.get(textControl) };
  putTextSelectionState(textControl);
  const currentState = { ...textSelectionStorage.get(textControl) };

  if (
    (selectionEnd - selectionStart === 0)
    && recentState.isSelected
  ) {
    // console.log('deselect');

    // a custom event will be created and dispatched in case ...
    // - there is nothing currently selected ... and ...
    // - there was a recent slection right before.
    textControl
      .dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('deselect', {
          detail: {
            recentState,
            currentState,
          },
        })
      );
  }  
}
// update text control related selection data.
function handleSelectText({ currentTarget }) {
  putTextSelectionState(currentTarget);
}

// enable text related, custom 'deselect' event handling.
function initializeHandleDeselectText(textControl) {
  const nodeName = textControl.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  const textType = ((nodeName === 'textarea') && 'text')
    || ((nodeName === 'input') && textControl.type)
    || null;

  if (
    (textType === 'text') ||
    (textType === 'search') // ... or some more ...
  ) {
    putTextSelectionState(textControl);

    textControl.addEventListener('select', handleSelectText);

    textControl.addEventListener('input', handleDeselectText);
    textControl.addEventListener('keyup', handleDeselectText);
    textControl.addEventListener('mouseup', handleDeselectText);
    textControl.addEventListener('focusout', handleDeselectText); 
  }
}


// custom 'deselect' event handling.
function logTextDeselection(evt) {
  const { type, detail, currentTarget } = evt;

  console.log({ type, detail, currentTarget });
}
// native 'select' event handling.
function logTextSelection(evt) {
  const textControl = evt.currentTarget;

  const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textControl;
  const selection = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

  console.log({ type: evt.type, selection });
}

function main() {
  const textControl = document.querySelector('#browser1');

  // enable text related, custom 'deselect' event handling.
  initializeHandleDeselectText(textControl);

  // native 'select' event handling.
  textControl.addEventListener('select', logTextSelection);

  // custom 'deselect' event handling.
  textControl.addEventListener('deselect', logTextDeselection);

  // default selected initial value.
  textControl.focus();
  textControl.value = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

  textControl.selectionStart = 12;
  textControl.selectionEnd = 19;

  // handle display of all available text selection states.
  document
    .querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', () => console.log([
      ...document
      .querySelectorAll('textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="search"]')
    ].map(elmNode => ({
      elmNode,
      isSelected: textSelectionStorage.get(elmNode).isSelected
    }))));
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
button { width: 27%; }
[type="search"] { width: 72%; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 85%; }
```

```html
<input id="browser1" type="search" placeholder="Search something ..."/>
<button>show select states</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `onblur`. This is called if you exit the input. For entring use `onfocus` instead of `onselect` (this is for a text selection in an input field).

```js
let sel1, last = 0;
   
setInterval(() => {
    if (sel1 === last) return;
    console.log(sel1);
    last = sel1;
}, 200);
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="javascript: sel1 = true" onblur="javascript: sel1 = false" placeholder="Suche nach etwas" id="browser1">
```

Comment: The opposite of *select* is a *deselect* and not loosing the focus. The OP handles text selection events of a text input. Thus handling `blur` most probably is not the correct solution.

Comment: @PeterSeliger `deselect` is not [available](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/wF2qN/).

Comment: I know, that's why one has to detect it from handling a lot of other events and maybe even create a custom/artificial *text related* `deselect` event.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating a function which clears each of the variables which you are binding to the inputs. Inside each input's click event handler, you can invoke this function to clear any variables which may have been set previously. After invoking the function, set the variable which corresponds to that element.

Something along the lines of

```
function clearFlags() {
sel1 = false, sel2 = false, sel3 = false; // etc
}
```

and then your inline event handler could be

```
<input type="text" onselect="javascript: clearFlags(); sel1 = true" placeholder="Suche nach etwas" id="browser1">
```